# Gdal Python Bindings and File Geodatabase API

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to get python 2.7 to work with GDAL/OGR and an ESRI file geodatabase.  There have been a few similar questions asked but the answers don't fully resolve my situation.

I have installed the 64-bit GDAL Core files from [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) I have also installed the Python Bindings and the File GDB.

The background to the problem is that when I run ogrinfo --formats from the command line it returns: "FileGDB" (read/write), when I run ogr from the command line I can see the layers in the Geodatabase **BUT** when I try to use the following code in Python in returns "None"

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')
ds = driver.Open(r"my file.gdb",0)
print driver
```

Ogr definitely works in python because the following code returns the correct response:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
ds = driver.Open(r"My Shapefile.shp",0)
print ds

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds = driver.Open(r"My GeoTiff.shp",0)
print driver
```

Does anybody have any pointers to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: I sense a slight confusion between OGR and GDAL. Try instead: `ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')`

Comment: I've tried that and still no joy.  It still returns nothing instead of the SWIG object that it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this was to add GDAL_DRIVER_PATH = C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins in the Environment Variables.

This was in addition to Mike Toews comment about the correct usage being `ogr.GetDriverByName('FileGDB')`

Comment: Difficult find! This can also be set in Python with `os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH'] = r'C:\...'`, either before importing ogr, or by calling `ogr.RegisterAll()` after setting the variable.

Comment: I was using the pre-built Python GDAL Windows binaries, which don't require GDAL to be installed. In addition to setting `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` to point at the location inside the `site-packages` directory, I had to ensure FileGDB.dll was on `PATH`. (I had to download FileGDB.dll from ESRI separately.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the File Geodatabase API with Python, read my post:
http://libjoe.blogspot.com/2014/02/python-wrapper-for-esri-file.html

Also, see the project page:
https://code.google.com/p/file-geodatabase-api-python-wrapper/

Enjoy!
Joseph Armbruster

Comment: This question is specifically about GDAL bindings, so your self-promotion makes little sense here (as opposed to the other question).