# Execute SQL in File Geodatabase

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, sql

Is there a way to execute SQL queries on file geodatabase from Python? I'm looking for the same functionality provided by arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute for SDE databases.

Comment: Are you looking to just do a `SELECT` to the file geodatabase, or a more complex query?

Answer (score 4):

Most Python queries are limited to a Where clause, however, you can execute a subquery in the Select_By_attribute tool. Please see the ArcGIS SQL Reference for more details. Also, the **[arcpy.da UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000)** and SearchCursor let you issue groupby, distinct, top, order by in a sql_clause along with the where_clause.

From the **[SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000)**:

> Coverages, shapefiles, and other nongeodatabase file-based data
>   sources do not support subqueries. Subqueries that are performed on
>   versioned ArcSDE feature classes and tables will not return features
>   that are stored in the delta tables. File geodatabases provide the
>   limited support for subqueries explained in this section, while
>   personal and ArcSDE geodatabases provide full support. For information
>   on the full set of subquery capabilities of personal and ArcSDE
>   geodatabases, refer to your DBMS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use arbitrary SQL (though likely with some limitations) with the [file geodatabase API driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html) of [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/). See my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42504/753) this related question: [ogr2ogr / GDAL remove features in FileGDB while in use by ArcGIS Server map service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/42492/753)

Also, if you are looking to do this with Python and on Windows take a look at this question: [Gdal Python Bindings and File Geodatabase API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/64864/753)